# Speech to Text API offline(Preferred) or online

Tags: python, c#, windows

I'm making a windows desktop application that needs to transcribe videos and I'm looking for a good free API to help me achieve that.
I looked a lot but most of the API's that I've found have bad accuracies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't work with .NET Core but if you're using the legacy .NET Framework (which is supported) you can use `System.Speech` to both recognize and synthesize speech offline.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.speech.recognition?view=netframework-4.8

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine?view=netframework-4.8

**Update 3/1/21:** `System.Speech` is now been ported to .NET Core.  The Nuget package is available at: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Speech

Comment: Windows only I take it?

Comment: Yes, Windows only.

Answer (score 1):

Google's Speech-to-Text API has state of the art accuracy, a simple interface, and client libraries in many languages. You get 60 minutes free per month.

Link: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/

If you want online API that is totally free, you most likely will not find it.

If you are willing to go offline, you will probably have to come up with a custom solution using the weights of some openly available deep learning model. Read some papers on state-of-the-art transcription models and see if any of the weights are available on GitHub. Keep in mind that performing such a task offline is very computationally expensive, and might require a GPU to give you results in a reasonable amount of time.